Question regarding proof of chain rule for vector fields
Section 8.20 of Calculus Vol. 2 by Apostol contains the following theorem:
Let $f,g$ be vector fields such that $f\circ g$ is defined over a neighbourhood of $a$. Suppose $g$ is diferentiable at $a$, with differential $g'(a)$, and suppose $f$ is differentiable at $g(a)$, with differential $f'(g(a))$. It holds that $f\circ g$ is differentiable at $a$ and $$(f\circ g)'(a)=f'(g(a))\circ g'(a).$$

Consider the difference $f(g(a+y)-g(a))-f(g(a))$ for small values of $||y||$.
Now, since $g$ is differentiable at $a$, there exists a linear map $g'(a)$ such that we have a Taylor formula of first order
$$g(a+y)-g(a)=g'(a)(y)+||y||\cdot E_g(a,y),$$
where $E_g(a,y)\to 0$ whenever $y\to 0$.
Similarly, since $f$ is defferentiable at $g(a)$, there exists a linear map $f'(g(a))$ such that $$f(g(a)+g(a+y)-g(a))-f(g(a))=f'(g(a))(g(a+y)-g(a))+||g(a+y)-g(a)||\cdot E_f(g(a),g(a+y)-g(a)).$$
This implies that $$f(g(a)+g(a+y)-g(a))-f(g(a))=f'(g(a))(g'(a)(y)+||y||\cdot E_g(a,y))\\
+||g(a+y)-g(a)||\cdot E_f(g(a),g(a+y)-g(a))\\
=f'(g(a))(g'(a)(y))+f'(g(a))(||y||\cdot E_g(a,y))\\
+||g(a+y)-g(a)||\cdot E_f(g(a),g(a+y)-g(a))\\
=f'(g(a))(g'(a)(y))+||y||\cdot E(a,y)\; (*),$$
where $E(a,0)=0$ and $$E(a,y)=f'(g(a))(E_g(a,y))+\frac{||g(a+y)-g(a)||}{||y||}E_f(g(a),g(a+y)-g(a))$$ if $y\neq 0...$

I have two questions regarding this

How to go from
$$f'(g(a))(g'(a)(y))+f'(g(a))(||y||\cdot E_g(a,y))\\
+||g(a+y)-g(a)||\cdot E_f(g(a),g(a+y)-g(a))$$ to $$ f'(g(a))(g'(a)(y))+||y||\cdot E(a,y)?$$
In other words, how to go obtain $(*)$?This is my main question

This is perhaps the minor question, but why does Apostol say "$E(a,0)=0$? I mean it clearly makes sense that this error is $0$, but is he implicitly assuming that $y=0$? Because otherwise why would he invoke this error between the element $a$ and $0$



When you write $E(a,0)$, yes, you are taking $y=0$ in $E(a,y)$, so of course there is zero error. Did you see how he defined $E(a,y)$ in the “where …” statement? What algebra do you not agree with?

@TedShifrin It's not that I disagree with the algebra. But I thought the way Apostol defined the last error (the one without subindex) was too arbitrary. But of course, if I accept this definition of $E(a,y)$ then it makes sense.

No, he defined it to be the error in the linear approximation of $f\circ g$, as makes perfect sense. He just needs to show it goes to $0$ faster than $|y|$.
